# Google Maps API v3 Geocoding Business Names

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

Is it possible to Geocode with the name of a business instead of an exact street address? The following geocoding request returns 0 results. I want to be able to send a business name, city, and state and retrieve the latitude and longitude. Here is what I have so far:

```
var business = "Neighborhood Theatre, Charlotte, NC 28205";
geocoder.geocode({'address' : business, 'region' : 'us'}, function(results, status) {
    console.log(status);
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, [Geocoding is specifically targeted at postal addresses.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)

> Geocoding is the process of converting addresses 
>   (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") 
>   into geographic coordinates 
>   (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739),

To geolocate business names, you want to use something like the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)

> The Google Places JavaScript library's functions enable your application to search 
>   for Places (defined in this API as establishments, geographic locations, or prominent 
>   points of interest) contained within a defined area, such as the bounds of a map, or 
>   around a fixed point.

Answer (score 1):

This is a better fit for gis.stackexchange.com, but at any rate, look into google places.  Geocoding revolves around addresses and the google places API revolves around places of interest like businesses.